# crictl does not show as many images as ctr

Tags: kubernetes

When listing images with **ctr**, it shows so many versions of the same images whereas **crictl** shows just one?
Take a look at nginx.
**crictl** shows just one but **ctr** sees 4 of them.

**Question:**
What is the reason that ctr sees more image versions than crictl?

crictl output:

```
sudo crictl image list
IMAGE                                      TAG                 IMAGE ID            SIZE
docker.io/calico/cni                       v3.26.0             5d6f5c26c6554       93.3MB
docker.io/calico/node                      v3.26.0             44f52c09decec       87.6MB
docker.io/library/busybox                  latest              ba5dc23f65d4c       2.16MB
docker.io/library/nginx                    latest              92b11f67642b6       70.5MB
docker.io/library/redis                    latest              170a1e90f8436       51.4MB
k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server   v0.6.2              25561daa66605       28.1MB
registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns            v1.10.1             ead0a4a53df89       16.2MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy                 v1.28.7             123aa721f941b       28.1MB
registry.k8s.io/pause                      3.8                 4873874c08efc       311kB
registry.k8s.io/pause                      3.9                 e6f1816883972       322kB
```

ctr output:

```
sudo ctr -n k8s.io image list
REF                                                                                                              TYPE                                                      DIGEST                                                                  SIZE      PLATFORMS                                                                                                                          LABELS          
docker.io/calico/cni:v3.26.0                                                                                     application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:c7c80d82dc4f85ac4d7f2345c940bc7f818bbea03c2043df89923c032d8ee7fc 89.0 MiB  linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x                                                                     io.cri-containerd.image=managed
docker.io/calico/cni@sha256:c7c80d82dc4f85ac4d7f2345c940bc7f818bbea03c2043df89923c032d8ee7fc                     application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:c7c80d82dc4f85ac4d7f2345c940bc7f818bbea03c2043df89923c032d8ee7fc 89.0 MiB  linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x                                                                     io.cri-containerd.image=managed
docker.io/calico/node:v3.26.0                                                                                    application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:5086f1ef0287886811fea4d545a4bbb75d9345367b1b1ad1aa4447af2ecbc4ea 83.5 MiB  linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x                                                                     io.cri-containerd.image=managed
docker.io/calico/node@sha256:5086f1ef0287886811fea4d545a4bbb75d9345367b1b1ad1aa4447af2ecbc4ea                    application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:5086f1ef0287886811fea4d545a4bbb75d9345367b1b1ad1aa4447af2ecbc4ea 83.5 MiB  linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x                                                                     io.cri-containerd.image=managed
docker.io/library/busybox:latest                                                                                 application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json                   sha256:650fd573e056b679a5110a70aabeb01e26b76e545ec4b9c70a9523f2dfaf18c6 2.1 MiB   linux/386,linux/amd64,linux/arm/v5,linux/arm/v6,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/mips64le,linux/ppc64le,linux/riscv64,linux/s390x io.cri-containerd.image=managed
docker.io/library/busybox@sha256:650fd573e056b679a5110a70aabeb01e26b76e545ec4b9c70a9523f2dfaf18c6                application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json                   sha256:650fd573e056b679a5110a70aabeb01e26b76e545ec4b9c70a9523f2dfaf18c6 2.1 MiB   linux/386,linux/amd64,linux/arm/v5,linux/arm/v6,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/mips64le,linux/ppc64le,linux/riscv64,linux/s390x io.cri-containerd.image=managed
docker.io/library/nginx:latest                                                                                   application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json                   sha256:6db391d1c0cfb30588ba0bf72ea999404f2764febf0f1f196acd5867ac7efa7e 67.3 MiB  linux/386,linux/amd64,linux/arm/v5,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/mips64le,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x,unknown/unknown            io.cri-containerd.image=managed
docker.io/library/nginx@sha256:18090843a20ba39719ca4f389d509063ea4fcce9d16c7168f62404b6d630bc3e                  application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json                   sha256:18090843a20ba39719ca4f389d509063ea4fcce9d16c7168f62404b6d630bc3e 67.3 MiB  linux/386,linux/amd64,linux/arm/v5,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/mips64le,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x,unknown/unknown            io.cri-containerd.image=managed
docker.io/library/nginx@sha256:6db391d1c0cfb30588ba0bf72ea999404f2764febf0f1f196acd5867ac7efa7e                  application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json                   sha256:6db391d1c0cfb30588ba0bf72ea999404f2764febf0f1f196acd5867ac7efa7e 67.3 MiB  linux/386,linux/amd64,linux/arm/v5,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/mips64le,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x,unknown/unknown            io.cri-containerd.image=managed
docker.io/library/nginx@sha256:ef1b8ca5417494c4eba0c5b3203c5f3f01ce9f288e2eb246b8fa9cddc7571b4c                  application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json                   sha256:ef1b8ca5417494c4eba0c5b3203c5f3f01ce9f288e2eb246b8fa9cddc7571b4c 67.3 MiB  linux/386,linux/amd64,linux/arm/v5,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/mips64le,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x,unknown/unknown            io.cri-containerd.image=managed
docker.io/library/redis:latest                                                                                   application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json                   sha256:3134997edb04277814aa51a4175a588d45eb4299272f8eff2307bbf8b39e4d43 49.0 MiB  linux/386,linux/amd64,linux/arm/v5,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/mips64le,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x,unknown/unknown            io.cri-containerd.image=managed
docker.io/library/redis@sha256:3134997edb04277814aa51a4175a588d45eb4299272f8eff2307bbf8b39e4d43                  application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json                   sha256:3134997edb04277814aa51a4175a588d45eb4299272f8eff2307bbf8b39e4d43 49.0 MiB  linux/386,linux/amd64,linux/arm/v5,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/mips64le,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x,unknown/unknown            io.cri-containerd.image=managed
docker.io/library/redis@sha256:928c906ee97444f42a76ae59bc23ad48b4ed8d755fd0584950a8fd28d93c1b58                  application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json                   sha256:928c906ee97444f42a76ae59bc23ad48b4ed8d755fd0584950a8fd28d93c1b58 49.0 MiB  linux/386,linux/amd64,linux/arm/v5,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/mips64le,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x,unknown/unknown            io.cri-containerd.image=managed
k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.6.2                                                                  application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:f977ad859fb500c1302d9c3428c6271db031bb7431e7076213b676b345a88dc2 26.8 MiB  linux/amd64,linux/arm,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x                                                                        io.cri-containerd.image=managed
k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server@sha256:f977ad859fb500c1302d9c3428c6271db031bb7431e7076213b676b345a88dc2 application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:f977ad859fb500c1302d9c3428c6271db031bb7431e7076213b676b345a88dc2 26.8 MiB  linux/amd64,linux/arm,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x                                                                        io.cri-containerd.image=managed
registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns:v1.10.1                                                                          application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:a0ead06651cf580044aeb0a0feba63591858fb2e43ade8c9dea45a6a89ae7e5e 15.4 MiB  linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/mips64le,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x                                                      io.cri-containerd.image=managed
registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns@sha256:a0ead06651cf580044aeb0a0feba63591858fb2e43ade8c9dea45a6a89ae7e5e          application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:a0ead06651cf580044aeb0a0feba63591858fb2e43ade8c9dea45a6a89ae7e5e 15.4 MiB  linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/mips64le,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x                                                      io.cri-containerd.image=managed
registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.28.7                                                                               application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:32559f5de7667ed71da428af8a2da612c24690738959e10fae127ea3a3ac2fdd 26.8 MiB  linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x                                                                                  io.cri-containerd.image=managed
registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy@sha256:32559f5de7667ed71da428af8a2da612c24690738959e10fae127ea3a3ac2fdd               application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:32559f5de7667ed71da428af8a2da612c24690738959e10fae127ea3a3ac2fdd 26.8 MiB  linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x                                                                                  io.cri-containerd.image=managed
registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8                                                                                        application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:9001185023633d17a2f98ff69b6ff2615b8ea02a825adffa40422f51dfdcde9d 304.0 KiB linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x,windows/amd64                                                       io.cri-containerd.image=managed
registry.k8s.io/pause:3.9                                                                                        application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:7031c1b283388d2c2e09b57badb803c05ebed362dc88d84b480cc47f72a21097 314.0 KiB linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x,windows/amd64                                                       io.cri-containerd.image=managed
registry.k8s.io/pause@sha256:7031c1b283388d2c2e09b57badb803c05ebed362dc88d84b480cc47f72a21097                    application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:7031c1b283388d2c2e09b57badb803c05ebed362dc88d84b480cc47f72a21097 314.0 KiB linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x,windows/amd64                                                       io.cri-containerd.image=managed
registry.k8s.io/pause@sha256:9001185023633d17a2f98ff69b6ff2615b8ea02a825adffa40422f51dfdcde9d                    application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:9001185023633d17a2f98ff69b6ff2615b8ea02a825adffa40422f51dfdcde9d 304.0 KiB linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x,windows/amd64                                                       io.cri-containerd.image=managed
sha256:123aa721f941b4b89eca29830c028ed96276b0fb5e24c83112b755c532babd3b                                          application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:32559f5de7667ed71da428af8a2da612c24690738959e10fae127ea3a3ac2fdd 26.8 MiB  linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x                                                                                  io.cri-containerd.image=managed
sha256:170a1e90f8436daa6778aeea3926e716928826c215ca23a8dfd8055f663f9428                                          application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json                   sha256:3134997edb04277814aa51a4175a588d45eb4299272f8eff2307bbf8b39e4d43 49.0 MiB  linux/386,linux/amd64,linux/arm/v5,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/mips64le,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x,unknown/unknown            io.cri-containerd.image=managed
sha256:25561daa666051dbc5204d6df0ed53882c24f906a2cb71357bf0b8771dc5ab11                                          application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:f977ad859fb500c1302d9c3428c6271db031bb7431e7076213b676b345a88dc2 26.8 MiB  linux/amd64,linux/arm,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x                                                                        io.cri-containerd.image=managed
sha256:44f52c09dececf0d842450cfbdcf6f1ce1e6eaf2d7183d643b9fbf77dde03a38                                          application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:5086f1ef0287886811fea4d545a4bbb75d9345367b1b1ad1aa4447af2ecbc4ea 83.5 MiB  linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x                                                                     io.cri-containerd.image=managed
sha256:4873874c08efc72e9729683a83ffbb7502ee729e9a5ac097723806ea7fa13517                                          application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:9001185023633d17a2f98ff69b6ff2615b8ea02a825adffa40422f51dfdcde9d 304.0 KiB linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x,windows/amd64                                                       io.cri-containerd.image=managed
sha256:5d6f5c26c655486ee59f7c517dbd383336f4ce2c0db77f7d5ffd015395deee6f                                          application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:c7c80d82dc4f85ac4d7f2345c940bc7f818bbea03c2043df89923c032d8ee7fc 89.0 MiB  linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x                                                                     io.cri-containerd.image=managed
sha256:92b11f67642b62bbb98e7e49169c346b30e20cd3c1c034d31087e46924b9312e                                          application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json                   sha256:6db391d1c0cfb30588ba0bf72ea999404f2764febf0f1f196acd5867ac7efa7e 67.3 MiB  linux/386,linux/amd64,linux/arm/v5,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/mips64le,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x,unknown/unknown            io.cri-containerd.image=managed
sha256:ba5dc23f65d4cc4a4535bce55cf9e63b068eb02946e3422d3587e8ce803b6aab                                          application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json                   sha256:650fd573e056b679a5110a70aabeb01e26b76e545ec4b9c70a9523f2dfaf18c6 2.1 MiB   linux/386,linux/amd64,linux/arm/v5,linux/arm/v6,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/mips64le,linux/ppc64le,linux/riscv64,linux/s390x io.cri-containerd.image=managed
sha256:e6f1816883972d4be47bd48879a08919b96afcd344132622e4d444987919323c                                          application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:7031c1b283388d2c2e09b57badb803c05ebed362dc88d84b480cc47f72a21097 314.0 KiB linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x,windows/amd64                                                       io.cri-containerd.image=managed
sha256:ead0a4a53df89fd173874b46093b6e62d8c72967bbf606d672c9e8c9b601a4fc                                          application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:a0ead06651cf580044aeb0a0feba63591858fb2e43ade8c9dea45a6a89ae7e5e 15.4 MiB  linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/mips64le,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x                                                      io.cri-containerd.image=managed
```